# Peeling floors polyurethane

Tags: polyurethane

[image]

Reclaimed wood floors were installed 7 years ago and maintenance recommendations was to buff and repoly every 5-10 years…I did this with the same company that installed the floors.  The floor finish obviously did not bond with the wood and the surface immediately peels from dog's feet, a fingernail scratch, or other pressures on the floor.  Of course, the contractor does not want to take responsibility for the floor, is not bonded, and is not guaranteeing the work. How do I repair the floors?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. *" Of course the contractor does not want to take responsibility"* Of course! :-| To be fair they may not be wholly responsible, but they have to at least share the blame since they did the work. *"How do I repair the floors?"* You may already be anticipating this, I think the only option now is to sand and refinish. I'd love to have more details about how the re-poly job was done, if you saw any of the process, but at the end of the day that might only help identify a possible cause and probably won't help with what to do now.

Comment: I did not see the process as we needed to vacate the house because of the oil based poly application. I was wondering about some sort of contaminate in the equipment they used?? I also wonder what the floors will

Comment: There are multiple possible causes of this type of adhesion failure. A common one is contamination of the surface the new varnish is going on to; for example if the homeowner maintains shine using a wax or other kind of floor polish if any remains it will of course prevent the fresh varnish from being able to bond properly. Another is an incomplete, or inadequate, scuffing (not buffing) of the old surface; scuffing is intended to provide a microtexture the new varnish can grip to. A failure to clean the old surface well, and/or to adequately scuff it, is absolutely 100% down to the contractor.

Comment: [contd] So one thing to do is to try to get the contractor to specify the steps they used when refinishing your floor **in writing**. Armed with this new knowledge you can spot if, at least on paper, they did a decent prep job. But you have to allow for 1) them saying they did X and Y but the guys doing the work dropped the ball in some way — either missed a step, or did a sloppy job, or 2) outright lies to cover their asses!

Comment: However there is a chance of a bad batch of the finish. I want to say I doubt it's the case, but actually there's no way to know for sure *unless you could test some of it now*. If this does happen to be the cause the contractor can't really be said to be responsible, although you could argue that they should have tested first there really isn't enough time in the modern age for that kind of diligence except for $$$$$$ work.